# Conceptual question about thinking way of Generics

Tags: c#, generics

I am an avereage C# coder and I have some difficulties in Generics. When I study the subject in order there is no problem. But when I see generic classes or methods in inner style I got some conceptual understanding problems. ;

For example If I see a code like `List<string>` I assume that There is a list class that means you can make some operations with string. There is not a problem with that. Bu what would I have to think about if I see a class like
`Catalog<Book>` etc. Is that mean there is a Catalog class and you can only do operations with book class? What would I have to think the way with the words when I see complex Generics?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, and also it sounds a bit  theory based, so may do better on other sites (e.g. Software Engineering)... Are you asking when to use generics vs inheritance, or how you'd implement a generic catalog / something else?

Comment: In _many_ (not all) usages of generics then you can translate `X<Y>` as `X of Y`. So, `List<string>` would be a `list of strings`. Thus, `Catalog<Book>` is likely a `catalog of books` (as opposed to say a catalog of dogs or cars).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Generics or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162247/use-generics-or-not)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there are some explanations below that helped my question a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that `List<string>` means "There is a list class that means you can make some operations with string".  That's sort of true; but not really.  `List<T>` means you have a way of operating on lists of objects, where `T` is the placeholder for the object type.  `List<string>` doesn't have any string specific functionality other than `string`s being the type that the list holds; all operations provided by the `List<T>` class are not related to strings, but to lists.

If you have a class which derives from `List<string>` then it may have `string` specific functionality, since in that case the class definition explicitly includes the string type; e.g.

```
void Main()
{
    var demo = new StringList(){"one","two","three","four"};
    Console.WriteLine(demo.MaxLength());
}

class StringList: List<string>
{
    public int MaxLength()
    {
        return this.Max(s => s?.Length ?? 0); //handles nulls
    }
}
```

We couldn't have a `MaxLength` function on `List<T>`, since if we had `int` as the type this method would have no meaning (i.e. as `int` doesn't have a `Length` property).  However, since `StringList` derives from `List<string>` we have a concrete type where we know that all items of this type would have a `Length` property, so it makes sense to have a method that can find the max length.

Regarding something like `Catalog<Book>`, the name (which is all we've got to go on) would imply that a class `Catalog<T>` exists, where there may be some restriction on T, but Book meets those restrictions (e.g. maybe there's a requirement that `T` implements some interface, such as `ICatalogItem`, which states that items have properties `Title`, `Creator` (e.g. author for a `Book` / director for a `Movie`), `Publisher`, `PublishDate`, and so on.  The `Catalog<T>` class would then provide a way of holding multiple items of these types, and would provide methods allowing you to search on these properties.

Note also that generics do not have to be collections; you can have a generic class which takes a single instance of a given type, or even a generic class which does not hold any "internal" value, but just provides operations on that type.  We often see the "single instance" use of generics in dependency injection, where generics are used to hold a singleton, such as:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new SqlServerDatabase(myDefaultConnectionString))
   .As<IDatabase>()
```

i.e. allowing any code in our system with functionality to integrate with an `IDatabase` to use a connection to our `SqlServerDatabase` instance; though through changing only this line of code (and the value of the connection string) to the below, we could switch this to a `MySqlDatabase` instance.

```
builder.RegisterInstance(new MySqlDatabase(myDefaultConnectionString))
   .As<IDatabase>()
```

An example of generics where we don't have any instance would be something like an `IComparer<T>` as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2.  By creating classes derived from this class we can create different comparisons between objects of certain types, such as we may wish to compare strings for length rather than value (or if getting more complex / real world, maybe for their Scrabble word score), e.g:

```
class StringLengthComparer: IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return Math.Sign((x?.Length ?? 0).CompareTo(y?.Length ?? 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Generics are easier to understand if we take the name literally.

> characteristic of or relating to a class or group of things; not specific.

I can write a specific class that performs operations on a certain object, like this:

```
public class BookStorage
{
    private Book _item;

    public void StoreItem(Book item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public Book RetrieveItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }
}
```

It's a pretty simple class, but if I want to handle other things (not just books) I end up with lots of classes that are all pretty similar to this one.

```
public class BookStorage
{
    private Book _item;

    public void StoreItem(Book item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public Book RetrieveItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }
}

public class StringStorage
{
    private string _item;

    public void StoreItem(string item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public string RetrieveItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }
}
```

And, in fact, my class doesn't really care whether the item is book or a string, because it doesn't depend on any of the members of a `Book` or a `string`.

So if we make the class more generic (less specific) we can allow consumers to provide the type argument later on. We normally call the unknown type `T` but this is just a convention.

We now have a generic storage class that will have the type `T` specified later. It is identical to the consumer and gets all the same type checking that it had when it was a specific class, i.e. if I create `new Storage<Book>()` it will behave just like the `BookStorage` class. However, I can now create new kinds of storage without adding more classes, such as `new Storage<string>()` or `new Storage<Customer>()`.

```
public class Storage<T>
{
    private T _item;

    public void StoreItem(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public T RetrieveItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }
}
```

I can also take this to the next level and say that I will depend on some behaviour within my generic class. For example, if I only want to store valid items I can add a constraint to `T` that says it must implement the `IValidatable` interface. This means I can no longer create a `new Storage<string>()` because it doesn't satisfy the constraint - but as long as `Book`, `Customer`, or `Building` satisfy the constraint I can use it for all of those.

```
public interface IValidatable
{
    public bool IsValid();
}

public class Storage<T> where T : IValidatable
{
    private T _item;

    public void StoreItem(T item)
    {
       if (item.IsValid()) 
       {
            _item = item;
       }
    }

    public T RetrieveItem()
    {
        return _item;
    }
}
```

To sum up, generics make your class less tightly bound to the types that it operates on, allowing the consumers to re-use the class for different types.

Comment: Nice explanation. Your last example isn't valid C# though - `public class Storage<T> where T : IValidatable`

Comment: @stuartd oops... mixed a bit of TypeScript in there by accident. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I have got the point more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

> For example If I see a code like `List<string>` I assume that There is a
>   list class that means you can make some operations with string.

Wrong. If you see `Foo<T>`, then `Foo` and `T` are not necessarily `class`es. They can be `interface`s as well. `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` is an example of a generic `interface`. `List` implements this `interface`. The only thing you know when you see `Foo<T>` is that `Foo` is some kind of a concept, either a `class` or an `interface` and it is doing something with `T`. In your example of `Catalog<Book>`, `Catalog` is either a `class` or an `interface` and is doing something with `Book`. Since the names here are speaking for themselves, one can deduce that we have a catalog of books.